# Equal Column Heights with Boostrap and Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style a gallery using Bootstrap and Flexbox where there is one large image and beside it is two smaller, stacked images and have both be the same height.

The container columns seem to be doing their job and staying the same height but I need the `img` within the column to fill the height of the container.

It works in Firefox if I use `height: 100%` on the `img` but this breaks in both Chrome and Safari.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
figure {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.rts-col {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rts-col col-8">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="rts-col col-4">
      <figure style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the markup and stylesheet: https://jsfiddle.net/tylorreimer/q8qe5p80/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D I hadn't realized I could insert the code into my question on SO. I just updated my question to include the minimal code markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as though you need nested flexboxes where you have multiple images on one side.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.rts-col.split {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rts-col col-8">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="rts-col col-4 split">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You and @LGSon essentially had the same solution but I went with your solution for the sake of less classes in my HTML markup. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `col-4` a flex container with `column` direction, you can then use `justify-content` and its `space-between` to align those 2 image top/bottom

Add `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between` to your `<div class="rts-col col-4">` so it becomes `<div class="rts-col col-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">`

*Note, I also removed some of your margins to make them align better*

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
.rts-col {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rts-col col-8">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="rts-col col-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="rts-col col-6">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="rts-col col-6">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1400x933">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I ended up going with @Paulie_D solution to keep my HTML a little cleaner.

Comment: @tylorreimer Perfectly fine, do not though, 3 classes in html is smaller than create extra CSS rules, which is the whole point with using a framework ... and to make it more easy to see in the markup what is going on.

Comment: I actually use a stripped down version of Bootstrap for just the basic grid. I would have had to add those extra classes in anyhow so it's still more minimal adding the styling to the one class.